# VSTS customize "Discussion" section

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are trying to move the section "Discussion" in our VSTS from the bottom between other sections. But we can't find this section in the WebLayout in the XML configuration and we can't find either a specification if it is a limitation. Some limitations was provided [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/weblayout-xml-elements#weblayout-element-syntax) but didn't tell about the "Discussion" field.

Any idea?

Comment: The discussion is not a field of the work item and it isn't existing in the layout.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t move the Discussion section, because the discussion is not a field of the work item and it isn't existing in the layout.